# How to store spring security session information in redis?

Tags: spring-security, redis, session-management

I am using Spring security for Authentication and Authorization in my application. I am using Neo4j database as backend and implemented userDetailsService for authentication.

However, whenever my application restarts, user is forced to login once again. 
To overcome this, i am thinking to store session information in redis database and load the data to Spring security Context whenever application gets started.

Kindly pass on if there are any articles and pointers to implement the same.

I am thinking of following implementation for it,
1) For every successful authentication, store user details and session details in redis.
This must be implemented in loadUserByUsername() method of UserDetailsService implementation
2) Remove the data from redis, whenver user logs out, Where can i do this information? Is there any spring security function where i can call this
3) Load all the data from redis to spring security whenever application restarts, again where do i need to write this logic?

Please let me know if i have missed any information.

Comment: This sounds like something your container should be handling (if you really need it), rather than Spring Security. Tomcat will persist sessions across restarts if you [configure it appropriately](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html), for example.

Comment: @LukeTaylor In SpringSecurity there is something called as PersistentTokenRepository to store tokens, can this be used for above use-case. Also, what would be the differences doing it in Spring Security or Tomcat container?

Comment: The container will persist the whole session, so the user will be able to continue as before after the application restarts. Spring Security can't (and shouldn't) do that since it isn't responsible for maintaining the HttpSession. Remember-me is explained in the documentation. You would generally use it when you don't want the user to have to log back in over a period of weeks or even months. It uses a long-term cookie which is an additional security risk and may not be appropriate. The lifetime will typically span many container sessions.

Comment: Also, how often does your application actually restart? You should probably expand your question to explain why you think it matters if a user has to log in again after an application restart. Does it really happen that often that it would make a difference? How long is the session-timeout in your application?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to implement a

- SecurityContextRepository that handles security context storage to reds
- Eventually a custom filter that retrieves/ stores session information (GenericFilterBean)

I think it is possible to just give the standard filter a different repository, but I am not sure, I needed my own implementation anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Store session in a redis is out-of the box functionality now

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure remember-me feature of Spring Security.

> Remember-me or persistent-login authentication refers to web sites being able to remember the identity of a principal between sessions. This is typically accomplished by sending a cookie to the browser, with the cookie being detected during future sessions and causing automated login to take place. Spring Security provides the necessary hooks for these operations to take place, and has two concrete remember-me implementations. One uses hashing to preserve the security of cookie-based tokens and **the other uses a database or other persistent storage mechanism to store the generated tokens**.

More information available in Spring Security documentation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/remember-me.html

You can use out of box implementations or inject your own (aforementioned redis).

Comment: Adding remember-me to an application isn't really a good solution for maintaining a transparent user experience between application restarts, which appears to be what the OP wants. Unless there's actually a separate application requirement for it then it's probably inappropriate.

Comment: @Luke: consider the case where you would like to persist a sessionId of an active user during deployments. For example, code deployments could be rolled out by switching the active container (app versions are deployed to separate containers) in an Apache config. Ideally application state should persist between container switches, by persisting a sessionId in a back-end such as Redis then this allows other persisted domain objects to be fetched by reference to the sessionId. Or is there a cleaner way of providing a continuous user experience whilst deploying code?

Comment: @norm see the link I posted in a comment above about tomcat session persistence. Application state isn't just the session ID, it's the whole serialized contents of the session, so how smoothly it goes will depend on whether those values are compatible with the new deployed code.

Comment: 2 yr old question, using remember-me is still the recommended solution?

Answer (score 0):

As Luke Taylor said, Tomcat's default action is serialize/deserialize sessions on container restart. 
[Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html)

pathname attribute of standard manager is the name of the serialization file. If you dont specify a path name attirbute the default is SESSIONS.SER
If you dont want to have sesssions back when restarted, you need to specify it as empty string value..